# Generating a gdbinit file

Tags: assembly, terminal, arm, gdb, command

I'm using a terminal called Termux on my android device and I want to create a gdbinit file so that I can use the command, "set disassembly-flavor intel". Can someone guide me through this process as it's hard to read the other disassemble tool?

Comment: What does "flavor intel" do on ARM device? I mean, nothing, but you tagged this as ARM, and most of the android devices *are* ARM, unless you have one of the few x86 ones, so it sort of sounds like you are confused.

Comment: What's the other disassembly tool? Are you running Android-x86? $ echo "set disassembly-flavor intel" >> .gdbinit in home directory...